# lsyncd and additional parameters for rsync

Tags: rsync

Currently Im using lsyncd to monitor data and sync them (same machine)

```
 settings{
    logfile      = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile   = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd_status.log",
    maxDelays    = 10,
    maxProcesses = 15,
 }

sync{
default.rsync,
source="/home/user/data/source_data/",
target="/home/user/data/synced_data/",
delete=false,
rsyncOpts={
"--remove-source-files",
"--delay-updates",
"--checksum"
}
}
```

The problem is I can't pass these parameters for rsync (remove-source-files, delay-updates and checksum)

Im using lsyncd 2.1.4

Here is the error:

```
Starting lsyncd: Error: error preparing /etc/lsyncd.conf: Parameter "rsyncOpts" unknown. (if this is not a typo add it to checkgauge)
```

Answer (score 4):

Information based on [documentation for version 2.1.x](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/wiki/Lsyncd%202.1.x%20%E2%80%96%20Layer%204%20Config%20%E2%80%96%20Default%20Behavior). Based on this your sync section should look like this:

```
sync{
    default.rsync,
    source="/home/user/data/source_data/",
    target="/home/user/data/synced_data/",
    delete=false,
    rsync={
        checksum = true,
        _extra = { "--remove-source-files", "--delay-updates" }
        }
    }
```

I assume that you are aware of what this additional rsync parameters do. Especially `--remove-source-files`.

This _extra parameter is based on the `lsyncd` documentation and man pages for `rsync`. You should try for yourself if it works.

Answer (score 0):

rsyncOpts is not a valid directive.

Should be something like:-

```
rsync     = {
                links = true,
                archive  = true,
                delete = false,
                compress = true,
                verbose = true,
                _extra   = {"--omit-dir-times","-e ssh -i /root/lsync/source_rsa","--progress"}
            }
```